# Upload a shapefile, generate model and save it to database

Tags: django, django-models, psycopg2, geodjango

I like to create a site where users upload their shapefiles (1 or many) and use the platform to query the data anytime they login.

So can someone help how can i do the below:

1. Generating a new model automatically for the uploaded shapefile
2. Then maintain the ORM to serve the data from database to that user when ever required.
3. What is the best strategy to recieve many shapfiles and storing in the database ?

Comment: This would be a complex solution that would require a fair amount of code. I hope I'm wrong, but I don't think you'll get an answer for this question on SO. You may want to consider revising it to ask a more specific question(s), even if that means creating several questions to eventually reach your end goal.

Comment: Thanks Jape, What i really require is 
1. "How can i create a model for any excel table or shapefile at run time before saving it to database ?"  Because its not possible to imagine the column names and their data types.

2. Also , like to know a simple strategy of loading those tables in database instead of loading each imported excel table as different table in the database.

Comment: Have you checked the GeoDjango Tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/ ? Maybe it can give you some ideas. Pay attention to the command line tool `ogrinspect` which can generate a model out of a shapefile.